# (Not all) port forwardings working correctly

Tags: port-forwarding, nat, fritzbox

I have two port forwardings configured on my internet router:

- router-external-ip=85.93.c.d:22 --> internal-host:22
- router-external-ip=85.93.c.d:8010 --> internal-host:22

(Having only the last one makes no difference.)

Using wireshark on the internet host I try to connect from shows:

```
00:05:52.383219 78.46.a.b -> 85.93.c.d TCP 58451 > 8010 [SYN] Seq=0 Win=5840 Len=0 MSS=1460 TSV=838066885 TSER=0 WS=6
00:05:52.410834 85.93.c.d -> 78.46.a.b TCP 22 > 58451 [SYN, ACK] Seq=0 Ack=0 Win=5792 Len=0 MSS=1452 TSV=907810728 TSER=838066885 WS=1
00:05:52.410885 78.46.a.b -> 85.93.c.d TCP 58451 > 22 [RST] Seq=0 Win=0 Len=0
```

Meaning the router is not correctly NATting the response back. WT*?

Am I doing something wrong here, or is this router (FritzBox 7390) just bad?

Note: the port forward on port 22 works fine, as does another port forward on port 223 to another internal host.

Comment: So you have two different external ports forwarding to the same internal port (22)?

Comment: Somehow, that seems to be at the center of the misery. But as I said, removing one doesn't improve the whole thing either. Shouldn't the NAT device know anyway which port was initially used since the set/socket (78.46.a.b, 85.93.c.d, 58451, 8010, tcp) is unique? So having multiple translations would do no harm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, FritzBoxes can't do that.

Comment: Please use the edit link on your question to add additional information. The Post Answer button should be used only for complete answers to the question.

Comment: The complete answer is, it is not possible as AVM support said. However they will add an error message instead of allowing you to configure something that will not work as expected.